# Search and replace sentence with spaces using sed command

Tags: sed

I am trying to use the sed command to replace some text in file.

```
echo 'native_transport_port: 9042' | sed -E 's/native_transport_port:/\W9042/native_transport_port:9080'
```

I get an error: `sed: 1: "s/native_transport_port ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'n'`

I tried `echo 'native_transport_port: 9042' | sed -E 's/native_transport_port:\s9042/native_transport_port:\s9080'`
But get an error: `sed: 1: "s/native_transport_port ...": unterminated substitute in regular expression`

I am basically trying to search for native_transport_port and replace 9042 with 9080.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to finish the `s` command with a final `/`:

```
sed -E 's/native_transport_port:\s9042/native_transport_port:\s9080/'
```

While I'm at it, `\s` doesn't mean anything special in the replacement section, it becomes `s`; so you should do

```
sed -E 's/native_transport_port:\s9042/native_transport_port: 9080/'
```

or, if you want to reproduce the whitespace as-is,

```
sed -E 's/(native_transport_port:\s)9042/\19080/'
```

which re-uses the matched text in the replacement.

If your `sed` doesn't support Perl-style `\s`, you can match on space instead:

```
sed 's/native_transport_port: 9042/native_transport_port: 9080/'
```

Comment: I tried echo 'native_transport_port: 9042' | sed -E 's/native_transport_port:\s9042/native_transport_port: 9080/'

But It still shows with port 9042 instead of 9080

Comment: That's weird, `echo 'native_transport_port: 9042' | sed -E 's/native_transport_port:\s9042/native_transport_port: 9080/'` gives the expected result on my system.

Comment: Interesting. I tried on a linux system and it works. On my mac it doesn't!

Comment: That is interesting, is the target macOS?

Comment: I am testing my scripts on macOS. But eventually I need to run on a linux machine. It would be great if I could get it working on mac and linux with the same script

Comment: Do you need to match any whitespace or can you use `sed 's/native_transport_port: 9042/native_transport_port: 9080/'`?

Comment: I think perhaps OSX `sed -E` only supports POSIX extensions - which would not include perl-style `\s` for whitespace?

Comment: @StephenKitt Works without -E and no \s

Comment: Confirmed `\s` needed in Ubuntu `sed` version `4.7`. I didn't see relevance of `-E`